# Apple pay button not showing in virtual box

Tags: ios, asp.net

I've implemented Apply pay button to my asp.net site and it shows in Iphone XR. But I tried it with macos catalina virtualbox version 10.15.3 I can't see the Apple pay button. Is apple pay button not working on virtual box?. Currently I don't have any mac book to get confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

ApplePay for Safari on Mac requires the [correct hardware](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201239).

Specifically, you need:

- A Mac with TouchID
- A Bluetooth connection to an Apple Watch connected to the same iCloud account
- A Bluetooth connection to an iPhone with TouchID or FaceID, again with the same iCloud account.

Obviously a virtual box can't satisfy the first requirement.

You may be able to get it to work with one of the other two options.

The ApplePay process is very secure so there is a good chance it won't work at all on virtual hardware.